# What tenses to use in writing meeting minutes?

Tags: tense

I understand that you must use past tense when writing minutes. However, there are some instances when I am not sure if past tense should be used as it would either change the meaning of the sentence or sound weird. Below are some situations which I have trouble with:

When something is in progress / happen in future. 
Example:

> 1) The team is checking on the machine. (Should it be: The team was    checking on the machine)
>   2) Checks on the system are being done.    (Should it be: Checks on the system was being done)
>   3) All the members    agree to build a new building. The construction of a new building    will start February next year (in February Year 2021). (Should it be:    All the members agreed to build a new building. The construction of a    new building would start February next year)
>   4) The Sun will rise at 5.20 am every morning in Sydney. (Should it be: The Sun would rise at 5.20 am every morning in Sydney).

When Something is not Certain.
Example :

> 5) If there are sufficient data to support the efficiency of the new system... (Should it be: If there were sufficient data to support the efficiency of the new system...)
>   6) If the project is successful... (should it be: If the project was successful)

Comment: Where did you see that past tense must be used for meeting minutes? It's like a narrative. They can be any number of tenses, just like in life.

Answer (score 1):

Tenses in writing meeting minutes purely depend on the nature of the work or job. If the matter is *still in effects,* you avoid past tense. Say -

> System checks *were being* done ~ System checks *are* done

Why? Because even at this moment, the *check* is done.

> The team *is checking* on the machines

...is it still in effect? If yes, you keep *..is checking.*

> All the members *agree* to build a new building [sic]. The construction of a new building *will start* February next year (in February Year 2021)

This can be changed according to the current status. So, you can write -

> All the members *have agreed* upon building a new building. The construction of a new building *will start* in February 2021

I did not get *sun's example* here as a meeting minute!

Something *uncertain* is again probability and putting *if* is sufficient. And, conditional sentences, in most cases, take simple present tense.

> *If* the project *gets* successful...

Comment: [in effect//if the project is or becomes successful]